# Remove all apostrophes in field with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a value in database and it contains a few apostrophes like...........

> It's a good day. He's so happy.

Result must be.....

> Its a good day. Hes so happy.

What T-SQL statement can I use to remove the apostrohe?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's not to disguise errors further down the line by changing data is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx), here's an example:

```
declare @value varchar(40)
select @value = 'It''s a good day. He''s so happy.'


select @value, replace(@value, '''', '')
```

---

If you want to update a column in a table, do it like this:

```
update table
set column = replace(column, '''', '')
```

---

It replaces all occurrences of a specified string value (in your case apostrophes) with another string value (in your case empty string).

Comment: What if I want to replace all @ and # and $ at the same time as well?

Comment: I believe that'll be `select @value, replace(replace(replace(replace(@value, '''', ''), '@', ''), '#', ''), '$', '')`

Comment: @Etienne just like YS stated :)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
Replace(ColumnName, '''', '')
```

Comment: tried that but i got the same results.  The issue is always the 2nd column.. i can move around the columns but it is always the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from information provided at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

> *string_expression*
> Is the string expression to be searched. string_expression can be of a character or binary data type.
> *string_pattern*
> Is the substring to be found. string_pattern can be of a character or binary data type. string_pattern cannot be an empty string (''), and must not exceed the maximum number of bytes that fits on a page.
> *string_replacement*
> Is the replacement string. string_replacement can be of a character or binary data type.

Example:

```
REPLACE ( 'Hello SQL' , 'SQL' , 'World' ) 

/* Output = "Hello World" */
```